# Using jquery how do I test if the bottom of an element is level with bottom of another element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element that is fixed when scrolling past a certain position, I want the element to become static when the bottom of that element is level with the bottom of another element.

So basically how do I test if the bottom of an element is level with the bottom of an element that is parallel to the fixed element.

This code handles making the element fixed, I just need to turn it off when the bottom of `var imgCon = $('#imageContent');` is level with the bottom of `var txtCon = $('#textContent');`.

```
var imgCon = $('#imageContent');
var txtCon = $('#textContent');
var offset = txtCon.offset();
var txtCon = offset.top - 60;
var txtbottom = $('#textContent').position().top + $('#textContent').outerHeight(true);
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= txtCon) {
    imgCon.addClass('fixed');
    imgCon.removeClass('floatImage');
    var contentWth = $('#postContent').width();
    var number = contentWth * 0.35;
    imgCon.css('width', number);
    $(window).resize(_.debounce(function () {
        var contentWth = $('#postContent').width();
        var number = contentWth * 0.35;
        $('#imageContent').css('width', number);
    }, 10));
} else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= txtCon) {
    imgCon.removeClass('fixed');
    imgCon.addClass('floatImage');
}
//some magic that tests whether bottom is level with parallel container bottom
if (($(this).scrollTop()) >= txtbottom) {
    imgCon.removeClass('fixed');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) on the elements to be compared. The function returns an object with attribute bottom that contains the info you are searching for.

browser support appears to be fairly universal. make sure that you dereference a jquery object if you work with this library, as getBoundingClientRect is a dom function.

Comment: Ah, that sounds useful, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what's the task. Maybe this snippet gives hint or can help.
I think that this method totally ignores browsers scrolling behavior.

```
// get value from 1. Element
offset = $('elem1').offset();
value1 = offset.top + $('elem1').height();

// get value from 2. Element
offset = $('elem2').offset();
value2 = offset.top + $('elem2').height();

// Compare
if(value1 == value2) alert('equal');
```

Comment: using `outerHeight(true)` will include padding borders and margins

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying, but I don't think this is the droid I'm looking for :)